# Running a command on a vagrant box via ssh keeps asking for a password

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I am trying to run a command on/in a vagrant box using ssh.
According to the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/ssh.html), `vagrant ssh -c <command>` should connect to the machine via ssh and run the command.

I tried this using a simple Ubuntu Server 16.04 box, but every time I get prompted for a password. Simply running `vagrant ssh` allows me to connect without providing  a password.

I used the following Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "osslack/ubuntu-server-16.04-no-unattended-upgrades"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0"
end
```

I tried to test it with the following command: `vagrant ssh -c "ls"`.

How can I run a command via ssh without being prompted for a password?

Answer (score 0):

So, after playing around with it some more, I found a workaround/solution.

When using vagrant ssh, anything after -- will be directly passed to ssh.

So running `vagrant ssh -- ls` will tell ssh to run the command ls.

This does not prompt for a password.